# Text appear from left to right

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want the caption of a image (which is not necessary is a real caption) appear when the image is hovered. The text **should appear from left to right** so it's container should grow on the X axis as the image is hovered. I have been able to make the  text appear on hover but the transition effect is where I am stuck.
This is what I have tried:

**CSS:**

```
.morbid {
  display: none;
  margin-left:10px;
}

a:hover + .morbid {
  position:relative;
  display: block;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a>
  <img src='.../goals/sia.png'> 
</a>
<div class="morbid">
This text will appear as you hover your mouse over the image.
</div>
```

Actually the whole `div` must grow, text remaining static and I want the text to be hidden unless the image is hovered.

Comment: Why have you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: `display` is not one of [**animatable properties**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties)

Answer (score 12):

You cannot transition the `display` property's change of value. The full list of properties which can be animated is available [in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-css).

For the content to **grow and appear** you need to transition the `max-width` (or `width`, if you can set a fixed width to the element) like done in below snippet.

```css
.morbid {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 0%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-width 1s linear;
}
a:hover + .morbid {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src='http://picsum.photos/400/200'>
</a>
<div class="morbid">
  This text will appear as you hover your mouse over the image.
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2c16s8bv/)

---

Alternately, if you want the text to grow from the center then you can make use of absolute positioning with `transform` like in the below snippet.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}
.morbid {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  max-width: 0%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: max-width 1s linear;
}
a:hover + .morbid {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">
    <img src='http://picsum.photos/400/200'>
  </a>
  <div class="morbid">
    This text will appear as you hover your mouse over the image.
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xn7utsL6/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `transition` property on the element you want to add a transition effect.

Make the caption grow and shrink in size:

CSS:

```
.morbid {
    /* display: none; */
    margin-left:10px;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 12pt;
    -webkit-transition: font-size 0.25s;
    transition: font-size 0.25s;
}

a:hover + .morbid {
    position:relative;
    /* display: block; */
    font-size: 16pt;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a>
    <img src='.../goals/sia.png'> 
</a>
<div class="morbid">
    This text will appear as you hover your mouse over the image.
</div>
```

I had to change `opacity` for the caption instead of changing the `display` property because the animation doesn't show when changing the display property.

Comment: Thanks. But I want the div to grow  from below, and not the opacity.

Comment: @user3769239: If you want the div with text to grow then you need to transition width like mentioned in my answer. Or, you just want the text to grow? As in, only the size of text to increase?

Comment: Actually the whole div must grow, text remaining static

Comment: And I want the text to be hidden unless the image is hovered

Comment: @user3769239 Ok in that case you'll need to transition width or max-width (sample present in my answer above)